# XML parser Jar confusion

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xslt, jaxp

I need to know which jar contains the following class

`com.ibm.xml.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar`

kindly help me

Comment: Try JarFinder (but it didn't find anything): http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/search/~com.ibm.xml.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar~

Comment: @Piyush Why do you need this class? The current answers suggest that there is no such class (readily available), maybe we can help with the underlying problem.

Comment: sry guys i was off for 2 days :(

Comment: the issue is resolved though and i did not need to find out the source for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code snippet:

```
System.out.println(com.ibm.xml.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
```

Answer (score 1):

this jar exists in `xml-apis.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `Maven` ?

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Then in the output look for: `com.ibm.`